# How do I limit Access to a Sharepoint 2013 app?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working on a voting app for Sharepoint 2013 online. I need to limit access to the app's polls to certain Active Directory groups. How do I ensure that administrators have full access, and other AD groups can only vote but not close or open polls?